# How to check if 3 columns are same and add a new column with the value if the values are same?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that look like this..

```
index   Column A    Column B    Column C
0        alice       alice       alice
1        nick        nick        john
2        juli        nick        alice
```

I want to check in `Column A, Column B and Column C` are equal or not. If equal, I want to add the the value as a new `Column D`. If not, add `None` to `Column D`

I did this so far..

```
def func(row):
    if ((row['Column A']) == (row['Column B']) == (row['Column C'])):
        df['Column D'] = df['Column A']
    else:
        df['Column D'] = None
```

When I applied the function using..
`df.apply (lambda row: func(row),axis =1)`, I am not getting the desired output.

I got something like this..

```
index   Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
0      alice        alice       alice        None
1      nick         nick        john         None
2      juli         nick        alice        None
```

whereas, I want the output to be like..

```
index   Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
0      alice        alice       alice        alice
1      nick         nick        john         None
2      juli         nick        alice        None
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

use [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

here you are taking a subset of the dataframe to compare and store to an array `arr` then comparing the first column of the array against the rest of the columns.

```
import numpy as np
arr = df[['A','B','C']].values
df['D'] = np.where((arr == arr[:, [0]]).all(axis=1),df['A'],None)
```

or

```
def func(row):
    if ((row['A']) == (row['B']) == (row['C'])):
        return row['A']
    else:
        return None

df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row),axis =1)
```

Comment: I got an error ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()```

Answer (score 1):

In your if clause you wrote:

```
(row['Column A']) == (row['Column B']) == (row['Column C'])
```

I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it. Have you tried this code below as your if clause?

```
((row['Column A']) == (row['Column B'])) and ((row['Column B']) == (row['Column C']))
```

Comment: The output is same as I got..not the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried
`df['Column D'] = np.where((((df['Column A'])==(df['Column B']))& (df['Column B'] == df['Column C'])),df['Column A'],None)`

and this worked! Thanks all for giving the idea.