# Check if many columns of a data frame are exactly the same

Tags: python, pandas

I am developing a clinical bioinformatic application and the input this application gets is a data frame that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'store': ['Blank_A09', 'Control_4p','13_MEG3','04_GRB10','02_PLAGL1','Control_21q','01_PLAGL1','11_KCNQ10T1','16_SNRPN','09_H19','Control_6p','06_MEST'],
                   'quarter': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2,2],
                   'employee': ['Blank_A09', 'Control_4p','13_MEG3','04_GRB10','02_PLAGL1','Control_21q','01_PLAGL1','11_KCNQ10T1','16_SNRPN','09_H19','Control_6p','06_MEST'],
                   'foo': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 9, 2,2,4,2,2], 
                   'columnX': ['Blank_A09', 'Control_4p','13_MEG3','04_GRB10','02_PLAGL1','Control_21q','01_PLAGL1','11_KCNQ10T1','16_SNRPN','09_H19','Control_6p','06_MEST']})
print(df)


 store  quarter     employee  foo      columnX
0     Blank_A09        1    Blank_A09    1    Blank_A09
1    Control_4p        1   Control_4p    1   Control_4p
2       13_MEG3        2      13_MEG3    2      13_MEG3
3      04_GRB10        2     04_GRB10    2     04_GRB10
4     02_PLAGL1        1    02_PLAGL1    1    02_PLAGL1
5   Control_21q        1  Control_21q    1  Control_21q
6     01_PLAGL1        2    01_PLAGL1    9    01_PLAGL1
7   11_KCNQ10T1        2  11_KCNQ10T1    2  11_KCNQ10T1
8      16_SNRPN        2     16_SNRPN    2     16_SNRPN
9        09_H19        2       09_H19    4       09_H19
10   Control_6p        2   Control_6p    2   Control_6p
11      06_MEST        2      06_MEST    2      06_MEST
```

This is a minimal reproducible example, but the real one has an uncertain number of columns in which the first, the third the 5th, the 7th, etc. "should" be exactly the same.

And this is what I want to check. I want to ensure that these columns have their values in the same order.

I know how to check if 2 columns are exactly the same but I don't know how to expand this checking across all data frame.

EDIT:

The name of the columns change, in my example, they are just two examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an efficient method you can hash the Series using [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html), making the operation `O(n)`:

```
pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df.T, index=False)
```

We clearly see that store/employee/columnX have the same hash:

```
store       18266754969677227875
quarter     11367719614658692759
employee    18266754969677227875
foo            92544834319824418
columnX     18266754969677227875
dtype: uint64
```

You can further use `groupby` to identify the identical values:

```
df.columns.groupby(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df.T, index=False))
```

output:

```
{   92544834319824418: ['foo'],
 11367719614658692759: ['quarter'],
 18266754969677227875: ['store', 'employee', 'columnX']}
```

Comment: I didn't know this. Unrelated question but, can you do this for an entire dataframe? Because, if this is possible, what I would really need would be a combination between the other answer and this.

Comment: @Manuel yes you can, this is already using the whole dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Refer here [How to check if 3 columns are same and add a new column with the value if the values are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642094/how-to-check-if-3-columns-are-same-and-add-a-new-column-with-the-value-if-the-va)

Here is a code that would check if more columns are the same and returns the index of rows which are the same

```
arr = df[['quarter','foo_test','foo']].values #You can add as many columns as you wish
np.where((arr == arr[:, [0]]).all(axis=1))
```

You need to tweak it for your usage

Edit

```
columns_to_check = [x for x in range(1, len(df.columns), 2)]
arr = df.iloc[:, columns_to_check].values
```

Comment: Thanks. The application will take different input every time with different column names and different numbers of columns. I need to do this checking dynamically.

Comment: @ManuelDominguezBecerra Are the columns you want to check always in odd number?

Comment: it should be. I know what are you thinking. Subset odd columns and then do the checking right?